# MOSS 2007 SqlDataSource

Tags: sql-query

could you please help, where can I find information, how can I set ODBC SqlDataSource on an aspx page, if I cannot edit the Web.Config file probably due to security reasons?
Is there any inline-code which can help configuring connection without Web.Config?

I have looked around, I could find post with possibly the similar problem here /however, without answer/:
http://ms-sharepoint.itags.org/q_sharepoint_173844.html

Comment: What are you trying to consume the data with?  A GridView?

Answer (score 0):

If by .aspx page you mean something like a web part page, maybe the fastest would be to create a DataSource in your site, using SharePoint Designer and consume data via web parts.

See example here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010355745.aspx